# Error al crear tabla temporal Mysql Php Pdo (mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' ...)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

tengo un procedimiento extenso que ejecutandolo directamente en mysql funciona, ahora cuando ya lo pongo en php me da error desde el inicio que es creando una tabla temporal desde donde voy a ir obteniendo datos para lo que sigue del reporte.
Este es el código que pruebo y al ejecutar de devuelve OK porque el $stmt -> execute() se esta ejecutando pero la tabla no se crea.

```
   $stmt = Conexion::Conectar()->prepare("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
        resultado_subdeterminante_temporal 
        (id int, idSubDeterminante int, posibles int, positivas 
        int)");

        if($stmt -> execute()){
           echo 'OK';
        } else {
           echo 'ERROR';
        }
        $stmt = null;
```

Estos son los Log MySql

```
2018-11-29 17:38:31 18908 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table 
mysql.column_stats: expected column 'min_value' at position 3 to have type 
varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).

2018-11-29 17:38:31 18908 [ERROR] Incorrect definition of table 
mysql.column_stats: expected column 'max_value' at position 4 to have type 
varbinary(255), found type varchar(255).
```

Ahora si yo tomo esa consulta y la ejecuto en mysql o phpmyadmin se crea ok la tabla:

```
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE 
        resultado_subdeterminante_temporal 
        (id int, idSubDeterminante int, posibles int, positivas 
        int)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No comprendo el error, que significan los errores del log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUCION**

Lo solucione Upgradeando MySql.

```
-> Entrar a CMD
-> Navegar hasta llegar a la carpeta xampp/mysql/bin/
-> Ejecutar el comando mysql_upgrade -uroot -p
-> Completar password de la base
-> Se upgradea MySql
-> El procedimiento ya funciona
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560207/failed-to-create-temporary-table-mysql-php-pdo-mysql-column-stats-expected-col/53560380#53560380